# Percentage change vs log change in a repeated measures or time series analysis

Tags: time-series, anova, repeated-measures, logarithm, percentage

I'm trying to measure growth over 8 weeks between two groups.

In essence it's an 8 (week) x 2 (group) analysis.

What is the best practice, percent change in my dependent variable across weeks (e.g. Percent growth between time 1 and time 2, percent growth between time 2 and time 3, and so on)

[image]
...

or log difference in my dependent variable across weeks (e.g. take the natural log of my dependent variables, then log difference in my dependent variables between time 1 and time 2, then time 2 and time 3, and so on)?

[image]

It seems like the numbers are approximately equal, but I'd like to hear other opinions too on best practices.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the values of the percent change. At very small values, the percent change will be nearly identical to the differences in logs. If you check out the code below, the first several values have the relatively large percent change of 1.0 (100%), compared with the very small percent change values near the end of the vector "n". You can take a look at the vectors created in the code below to see at what point the values begin to diverge. At a percent change of 1, the deviation from the differences in logs is substantial, and I would not use them interchangeably. It's up to you to decide at what value the percent change deviates too greatly from the differences in logs.

```
library(dplyr)
n <- seq(0, 10000, .1)
pct.change <- ((n - lag(n)) / lag(n))
log.change <- log(n) - log(lag(n))
df <- data.frame(n, pct.change, log.change)
head(df)
plot(df$pct.change, df$log.change)
```

[image: Percent change versus difference in logs]